Use "with" in all CRUD functions
We have some issues with FastAPI (reading and "lost" data from database), so we use with instead of Depends.
Is it a good practice?
with SessionManager() as db:

    @router.get("/{id}", response_model=...)
    async def get_by_id(id: UUID) -> JSONResponse:
        result = crud_xxx.get_by_id(db, id)

    @router.get("/{text}", response_model=...)
    async def get_by_text(id: UUID) -> JSONResponse:
        result = crud_xxx.get_by_text(db, text)

and before:
@router.get("/{id}", response_model=...)
async def get_by_id(id: UUID, db: SessionLocal = Depends(deps.get_db)) -> JSONResponse:
    result = crud_xxx.get_by_id(db, id)

Is there another way to do this?

This doesn't do anything. You're only defining your API endpoints within the with block. By the time they're actually executed, the with context is gone.

You should search around first and maybe you might have found this example and explanation first. You may need to commit (and rollback on failure) the relevant data if you were losing data.

Thanks to help me. So, using "with" in all function is fine. Or better, using dependencies.

What you've done won't actually work. This what I do in some of my code:
@router.get("/{id}", response_model=...)
async def get_by_id(id: UUID) -> JSONResponse:
    with SessionManager() as db:
        result = crud_xxx.get_by_id(db, id)

@router.get("/{text}", response_model=...)
async def get_by_text(id: UUID) -> JSONResponse:
    with SessionManager() as db:
        result = crud_xxx.get_by_text(db, text)

Note that I've often gotten the impression that this is not necessarily  recommended practice, and that the Depends based approach is better. I don't know why exactly, though.
I've also assumed that whatever your SessionManager is also does all the needed things to actually manage sessions, such as rolling back on failures etc.

Using with to manage database sessions in FastAPI is not a common pattern. The Depends dependency injection is generally recommended because it allows FastAPI to manage the lifespan of the session properly and is more consistent with the dependency injection system that FastAPI uses. However, if you are experiencing issues with Depends, it might be due to how sessions are being handled within the dependency or the specific context in which the dependency is used.
Here is an example of how you might typically use Depends with a database session in FastAPI:
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from . import models, schemas, crud
from .database import SessionLocal, engine

app = FastAPI()

# Dependency
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

@app.get("/{id}", response_model=schemas.YourSchema)
async def get_by_id(id: UUID, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    result = crud.get_by_id(db, id)
    if not result:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Item not found")
    return result

@app.get("/{text}", response_model=schemas.YourSchema)
async def get_by_text(text: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    result = crud.get_by_text(db, text)
    if not result:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Item not found")
    return result

